# Can I add "16 pt" option to font pulldown menus?

Tags: macos, finder, font

Finder and all apps jump from 14pt to 18pt in dropdowns.  Can a 16pt be added?[image: here's a typical example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a flaky problem, or at least the solutions are flaky. As such, some apps, e.g. Mail, go through the motions but don't actually add the new size. Additionally, it may vanish at some undetermined time in the future. But for the present….

From within the app (e.g. TextEdit) that you want to see 16 pts, pull up the font dialogue (Cmd-T). In the upper-left corner, you should see a dropdown button with a gear icon on it. Click that and near the bottom select 'Edit Sizes…'.

[image: Edit Sizes…]

[image: New Size]

In the 'New Size' field, type '16' and then click the '+' button below it. Click done. Quit and re-launch the app.

Comment: Wow... I've used Mac since before Mac (I owned an Apple ///) and I did not know of this option. I almost never use the Font panel itself.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that they advertise it much. Personally, I just wish that they'd start with 16 and 20 points in there but it doesn't work that way. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I add it all the time - like the size - but I can tell you, it never stays and hasn't for years and many OS iterations.

Comment: Thanks very much for the info. For now my need is mostly in Pages.